# CRM 2011 Rollup Queries: How to use operators to arrive at a percentage?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to sort out how to use rollup queries and goals. What I'm trying to do is have a rollup query that produces a percentage:

(# of service activities with status code X) / (total # of service activities)

Then I want the "goal" to track this %. It's not the total count or sum that matter for this goal, but the proportion.

Is this possible, or can rollup queries and goals only be used with raw counts and aggregates (e.g. # of appointments with status X, or sum of revenue in time period X)?